# How to extract longitude and latitude from a link

Tags: python, extract, text-extraction

From the following link, I am trying to extract the longitude and latitude. I found similar posts but not one with the same format. I'm new to regex/text manipulation and would appreciate any guidance on how I might do this using Python. The output I'd like to have from this example is

```
latitude = 40.744221 
longitude = -73.982854
```

Many thanks in advance.

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=1&center=40.744221%2C-73.982854&language=en&zoom=15&markers=scale%3A1%7Cicon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyelp-images.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fassets%2Fmap-markers%2Fannotation_32x43.png%7C40.744221%2C-73.982854&client=gme-yelp&sensor=false&size=315x150&signature=OjixVjNCwF7yLR5tsYw2fDRZ7bw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a module for parsing URLs in the standard library

```
from urllib import parse

# Split off the query
_, query_string = parse.splitquery("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=1&center=40.744221%2C-73.982854&language=en&zoom=15&markers=scale%3A1%7Cicon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyelp-images.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fassets%2Fmap-markers%2Fannotation_32x43.png%7C40.744221%2C-73.982854&client=gme-yelp&sensor=false&size=315x150&signature=OjixVjNCwF7yLR5tsYw2fDRZ7bw")

# Parse the query into a dict
query = parse.parse_qs(query_string)

# You can now access the query using a dict lookup
latlng = query["center"]

# And to get the values (selecting 0 as it is valid for a query string to contain the same key multiple times).
latitude, longitude = latlng[0].split(",")
```

For this usecase I would avoid regular expressions. The `urllib` module is more explicit, will handle all aspects of URL encoding and is well tested.

Another third party module for handling URLs is the excellent [YARL](https://yarl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: last line should be:
latitude, longitude = latlng[0].split(",")

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this expression might return our desired output:

```
center=(-?\d+\.\d+)%2C(-?\d+\.\d+)
```

#### Test with `re.findall`

```
import re

regex = r"center=(-?\d+\.\d+)%2C(-?\d+\.\d+)"

test_str = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=1&center=40.744221%2C-73.982854&language=en&zoom=15&markers=scale%3A1%7Cicon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyelp-images.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fassets%2Fmap-markers%2Fannotation_32x43.png%7C40.744221%2C-73.982854&client=gme-yelp&sensor=false&size=315x150&signature=OjixVjNCwF7yLR5tsYw2fDRZ7bw"

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Test with `re.finditer`

```
import re

regex = r"center=(-?\d+\.\d+)%2C(-?\d+\.\d+)"

test_str = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=1&center=40.744221%2C-73.982854&language=en&zoom=15&markers=scale%3A1%7Cicon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyelp-images.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fassets%2Fmap-markers%2Fannotation_32x43.png%7C40.744221%2C-73.982854&client=gme-yelp&sensor=false&size=315x150&signature=OjixVjNCwF7yLR5tsYw2fDRZ7bw"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/EhYjIe/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/EhYjIe/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple `re.search` on the string with tuple packing:

```
lattitude, longitude = re.search(r'center=(.*?)%2C(.*?)&', s).groups()
```

where `s` is your string (link).

**Example**:

```
import re

s = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?scale=1&center=40.744221%2C-73.982854&language=en&zoom=15&markers=scale%3A1%7Cicon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fyelp-images.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fassets%2Fmap-markers%2Fannotation_32x43.png%7C40.744221%2C-73.982854&client=gme-yelp&sensor=false&size=315x150&signature=OjixVjNCwF7yLR5tsYw2fDRZ7bw'

lattitude, longitude = re.search(r'center=(.*?)%2C(.*?)&', s).groups()

print(lattitude)  # 40.744221
print(longitude)  # -73.982854
```